# Connect to a Heroku app after directory (and all other data) deleted on local machine

Tags: heroku

I lost all the data on my localmachine (Macbook Pro)  and, to make matters worse, the repo for a Rails app hosted on Heroku has also been deleted on github.  Since I lost all the data on my localmachine, whatever security keys I had installed have also been deleted so if I try to connect to Heroku it won't even recognize me.  What can I do in this situation to download the app and export the database?

Answer (score 0):

Are you still able to log into heroku.com? If so, you should be able to [set up the heroku CLI again](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart) with a new public key. Then you should be able to use `heroku git:clone APP` to get the code from heroku.

With your database, there should be options for managing it on heroku.com or via the heroku CLI (e.g. `heroku pg:pull` if you're using postgres).